# Node.js script fails to run from flask python subprocess.run

Tags: python, node.js, flask, import

I have a node.js script running on ubuntu (stripped down to only include issue):

```
import axios from 'axios';
console.log("axios import ok")
```

This can be run fine from command line using node /home/verifier/verify.js

and outputs "axios import ok" to the console.

We need to execute this node script via api using flask:

```
from subprocess import check_output, call, run, PIPE


@api.route('/cbor', methods=['POST'])
def cbor():
    #res = request.json
    
    #cbor = res["cbor"]
    p = run(f"node /home/verifier/verify.js", shell = True,stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, universal_newlines = True)

    return str(p), 200
```

The flask file (api.py) is in the same directory as verify.js

This returns a string of the CompletedProcess object:

```
stderr="/home/verifier/verify.js:2\nimport axios from 'axios';\n ^^^^^\n\nSyntaxError: Unexpected identifier\n at
Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)\n at Object.Module._extensions..js
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)\n at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)\n at tryModuleLoad
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)\n at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)\n at
Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)\n at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)\n at
bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)\n")
```

So when we try to run the node script from within flask the import fails with

```
Unexpected identifier atModule._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
```

into stderr

The stack is direct. Flask is directly receiving from the port rather than using nginx / gunicorn.

so just

```
api = Flask(__name__)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    api.run(host='DropletIP removed')
```

I assumed it was a path issue. But the node script appears to be being started in the correct dir as if i run

```
p = run(f"pwd", shell = True,stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, universal_newlines = True)

    return str(p), 200
```

It returns

CompletedProcess(args='pwd', returncode=0, stdout='/home/verifier\n', stderr='')

does anyone have a suggestion as to why when running the script through subprocess.run it causes the node.js imports to fail? I can run normal js code but cannot import when opened via flask.